# Unable to use pkcs11-tool with custom hsm roles

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#11, hsm, opensc

i am working on a HSM which has a custom user role: crypto user.
how can i use pkcs11-tool to login or work with that user on Hsm?
it works with user or SO not sure how can i use with custom roles specific to hsm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given [the implementation of pkcs11-tool](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/blob/2b78374e37b44e06a9f9ca45fc9ccf72081a27f6/src/tools/pkcs11-tool.c#L847) it is not possible to specify `CKU_CRYPTO_USER`.

It would make sense to patch `pkcs11-tool` to support numeric values for the `--login-type` option.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thnak You, this is fine.